# Could not resolve dependency for retrofit

Tags: android

I still got error even after changing retrofit 2.3.0 to 2.6.2 I am stucking with this for a long time please help me to resolve this

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.blog"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:convertor-gson:2.6.2'
```

Comment: What kind of error is it?

Comment: can you add your other build.gradle file

Comment: ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0 this is the error message

Answer (score 0):

Your external libraries should be inside `dependencies`.

---

> It should something like below

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.blog"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies{
    // other external libraries
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:convertor-gson:2.6.2'
}
```